# Are there killcams for dual wield kills?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've never seen this actually happen when using it? AKA Using Dual wield to finish someone off or by Sneaking and getting an instant kill.

Namely by using a Power Attack with Dual Wield? Is it even possible?

Also is it possible to decapitate when dual wielding?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are killcams for every type and combination of weapon

here is a video of dual swords (not very.. good but its first one i found on youtube)

My main on skyrim was dual maces and they do decapitate, often.

Comment: What about Sneak Kills, or are those the same as killcams. I've heard that when power attacking with dual weild (aka pressing both at the same time, you will not actually get the killcam)

Comment: killcams proc randomly, power attacks do not hinder or improve your chances of getting it. Also some of the kills in that video were sneak kills.

Comment: Dual-Maces decapitating? Wtf.

Comment: yes @Seloniath. The animation is the character smashes the stomach with one mace, and when the opponent keels over you downward strike the head clean off.